# eventListener doesn't work after imported HTML

Tags: javascript

I got this app in progress:

https://jsfiddle.net/cg7Lwo29/2/

So, I'm working with web pack and I'm trying to hold everything in different files. 
My HTML should be pretty basic for this ToDO app, so I'm trying to make just a few divs and change the content with JS.

So, I have this HTML code in a different js file and I import it in the index.js and then it goes to main.js

```
const createProject =
`
<div class="container">
<div class="container-header">ADD A PROJECT</div>

<form id='todo-form' action="get">
    <div class="todo-title"><span>Title</span><br><input id='title-input' type="text" name="" id=""></div>
    <div class="todo-description"><span>Description</span><br><input id='description-input' type="text" name="" id=""></div>
    <div class="todo-date"><span>Date</span><br><input id='date-input' type="date"></div>
    <div class="todo-priority"><span>Importance</span><br><input id='range-input' type="range" min='1' max='10' value='5' class='slider' id='myrange'></div>
    <div class="todo-button"><button id='submit-project'>Add project</button></div>
</form>  

</div>
`

export default createProject;
```

Everything good, I import it and it works HTML wise but JS doesn't recognise it I think.

I get a null error at first eventListener

```
        formSubmit.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
            e.preventDefault();
```

But if I put the HTML directly, without importing it, it works just fine. How can I solve this?

TL:DR:
HTML imported gives null error.

Cheers

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I can't find any html element with the id of #submit-project. What are you trying to select?

Comment: in createProject, it's a form in a div which has a button with #submit-project. My problem is that I import the JS file with the form(the one that I put in post) but it gives me null error when I put an eventListener on the button or form itself.

Comment: where is the variable `formSubmit` defined? and *I get a null error* - exactly what is the error

Comment: are you running `const formSubmit = document.querySelector('#submit-project')` before the HTML is loaded? that will cause the problem

Comment: So, I have a button that sets the HTML to createProject's HTML. After this, I set the const formSubmit. In other words, HTML is empty at first load of the page, a button puts the form on and a button in the form should do smth but here I get null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add an eventListener when the HTML code for that particular id doesn't exist yet. That's why it returns as null. Make sure that you add the eventListener to the js file that contains the const createProject like this:

```
const createProject =
`
<div class="container">
<div class="container-header">ADD A PROJECT</div>

<form id='todo-form' action="get">
    <div class="todo-title"><span>Title</span><br><input id='title-input' type="text" name="" id=""></div>
    <div class="todo-description"><span>Description</span><br><input id='description-input' type="text" name="" id=""></div>
    <div class="todo-date"><span>Date</span><br><input id='date-input' type="date"></div>
    <div class="todo-priority"><span>Importance</span><br><input id='range-input' type="range" min='1' max='10' value='5' class='slider' id='myrange'></div>
    <div class="todo-button"><button id='submit-project'>Add project</button></div>
</form>  

</div>
`

formSubmit.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
            e.preventDefault();

export default createProject;
```